# Get the date after a word?

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.0

I have a huge text wall where I need to search for the born or death date, the date usually comes in the following formats:

> some more text. *Born* **December 5, 1942** in Sumner and more text

or

> some text *born* in City, State, on **August 8, 1922**, more text

or

> some text *died* Wednesday, **November 3, 2010**, more text

or

> some text *passed away* **Friday, December 19, 2008** more text

or

> some text *died* **January 11, 2007**, more text

In short the date usually comes a few words after the born word.

I assume that the best way to get this date would be by using a regex but correct me if I am wrong here.

Here is what I came up with to get the date but I am still far from getting only the date:

```
(?=born\s|died\s|passed\saway\s)(\w+.*)(\w+\s\d+,\s\d+)
```

Problem is my regex doesn't work entirely, it will eat the month word, how do I correct this or is there a better regex or way to do this ?

I know I could use the below to get the date only but I need to know the event as well:

```
(\w+\s[0-9]{1,2},\s[0-9]{2,4})
```

Comment: By "eat the month word" do you mean it's including the last character of the month in the second group? That's what it did when I ran your regex.

Comment: @Kit yes that is what happens and I am not sure on how to fix it. I tried to do another backlook on it but doesn't seem to work. It was also a good opportunity to ask if this was the best way to get this piece of data I needed as well as if my regex was on the right track :)

Comment: Ok, and are you wanting the date only, or the date and the "event" (e.g. born). And as one group or two groups?

Comment: @Kit yes I need to know the event and the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a lazy repeat: `(?=born\s|died\s|passed\saway\s)(\w+.*?)(\w+\s\d+,\s\d+)`

Comment: is there a way to stop it from going to the next phrase if it found the word ? I have tried using `RegexOptions.Singleline` but it doesn't seem to respect it and always keep going until it finds a date even if it is unrelated to that phrase. For example "this phrase ends here." then there is a new line and another phrase, it will go into it searching for a date, that is too long.

Answer (score 1):

This one works well with explicit capture groups, ignore case, and ignore pattern whitespace. It tolerates some bad formatting (e.g. extra or missing spaces) Overkill I'm sure.

```
# get the event
(?'Event'born|died|passed\saway)
# skip junk (note, not using \s for whitespace)
[ \t].*
#get the date in Month, dd, yyyy form (including abbreviated months)
(?'Date'
  (?'Month'
     # month can't start unless there's whitespace before it
     (?<=\s)    
     # month can be abbreviated or not
     (Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Ap(ril)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)    
  )
  \s*
  (?'Day'\d{1,2})
  \s*,\s*
  (?'Year'\d{2,4})
)
```

Comment: thats actually pretty nice, also learned that I don't need to use <> for naming the groups it can be anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem with it eating your month word is because of the second capture group (\w+.*).  If you think about it, a month will be a word and any \w will match it.  So your approach is slightly flawed.  Based on your example it would appear that the date format is consistent with the Month spelled out and in the form "month dd, yyyy".  If we can assume that being so, I suggest tweaking your regex to include the 12 possible month names so it will solve your "eating" the month word from other wildcard words that you don't care about...

```
 (?=born\s|died\s|passed\saway\s)(\w+.*)((January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s\d+,\s\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
(?=born\s|died\s|passed\saway\s)(\w+.*?)(\w+\s\d+,\s\d+)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
(born|died|passed\saway)\s(\w.*)\s(\w+\s[0-9]{1,2},\s[0-9]{2,4})
```

It's similar to what's by others, but you add in a space after to ensure nothing gets eaten. Also, saves a little code by having the \s outside the parentheses instead of with each option.